# Is gulp lying about how long a task takes?

Tags: gulp

Gulp says it took 13ms to run my "js" command, but then it hangs for another 2 seconds or so after it's "complete".

So either my task didn't complete in 13ms, or gulp is twiddling its thumbs for an extra two seconds after it's done. Which is it? Is there a way to fix this? I'd like to know how long my tasks are really taking; maybe I can trim some fat off.

Comment: You are probably not returning the stream, so it has no way to know how long the task really takes. [Make sure you have Async support set up correctly.](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support)

Comment: @OverZealous: Aha! Thank you! If you make that an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Although multi-tasks are still timed weird. `gulp.task('js',['pace','mainjs']);` reports that `mainjs` took 11s, `pace` took 11s, and `js` took 9us, when really `mainjs` took the 11s, and `pace` takes about half a second, and `js` should be either 11s if it runs them concurrently, or 11.5 if not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to have [async tasks set up correctly](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support).  This usually means simply returning the stream, but you can also accept a callback or return a promise:

```
gulp.task('foo', function() {
    return gulp.src()...
});

gulp.task('foo', function(cb) {
    // use the callback however
    doAsyncThing().on('done', cb);
});
```

Second, tasks are *always* run simultaneously, unless they have a dependency on each other.  If you need to run tasks in a series, rather than parallel, and cannot use the built-in dependency resolution, then use [my library, `run-sequence`, designed specifically for this scenario.](https://npmjs.org/package/run-sequence).